# counterexample for cycles in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to find a counterexample to the statement that a graph that has cycles containing x and y and a cycle with all 3
I know this is a false statement

Answer (score 4):

Cycle with $(x,y)$, cycle with $(y,z)$, cycle with $(x,z)$ but no cycle with all 3.

[image]